# Rotating a 3d vector in THREE.js on two axes

Tags: javascript, vector, 3d, three.js

Sorry for posting possible duplicate.

I have two 3d vectors:

center ( 0, 0, 0 )

orb ( 0, 0, 100 )

I want to rotate the orb-vector around the center-vector on both X and the Y axes.
What I'm trying to achieve is the make and object always be in view of the camera in the direction it's facing.

I've tried this but with no luck.

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 100 );
vector.applyAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ), Math.PI * 0.5 );
vector.applyAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ), Math.PI * 0.5 );
orbBall.position.copy(vector);
```

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Could you tell us more about `orbBall`?

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Mr_Pouet see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around this issue I realise that it's quite advanced mathematics.
Check out this lecture about quaternions if you're interested:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHVwd8gYLnI

So I used @bjorke suggestins and used a dummy object, and it works well.

```
var container, scene, camera, renderer, controls, stats;
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;

scene = new THREE.Scene();

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
camera.position.set(100, 100, 400);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
scene.add(camera);

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
container = document.getElementById( 'ThreeJS' );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff); //new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
light.position.set( 30, 80, -15 );
scene.add(light);


var boxGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10);
var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(1000);
scene.add( axes );

var cameraObj = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeo, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0x888800}));
scene.add(cameraObj);

var orbSpace = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(orbSpace);
var orbBall = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeo, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0x880088}));
orbBall.position.set(0, 0, cameraObj.position.z + 100);
orbSpace.add(orbBall);

animate();

var camX = 0.3;
var camY = 0;
function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    camY += 0.02;
    if (camY >= 2) camY = 0;

    cameraObj.rotation.x = Math.PI * document.querySelector('#volume').value;
    cameraObj.rotation.y = Math.PI * camY;
    orbSpace.position.copy(cameraObj.position);
    orbSpace.rotation.copy(cameraObj.rotation)


    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

Here's a codepen about how it works:

http://codepen.io/arpo/pen/RrpMJJ

You can update the X angle in the uper right corner

Answer (score 1):

"What I'm trying to achieve is the make and object always be in view of the camera in the direction it's facing."

If you are simply trying to ensure that `orbBall` always faces the camera, and both `orbBall` and the `camera` are part of the THREE `scene` then you can just use `lookAt` like so:

```
orbBall.lookAt(camera.position);
```

if you need to align a particular side of `orbBall` you can use a null dummy `Object3D` to do it, by adding the dummy node to the scene and orbBall to the dummy, in something like this:

```
dummy = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(camera); // "camera" is defined however
scene.add(dummy);
dummy.add(orbBall); // "orbBall" is created as usual
// ... not to align dummy+orbBall
dummy.lookAt(camera.position);
// ...and you can just rotate orbBall around "inside" dummy, just once,
///       to face however you like
```

Comment: Thanks @bjorke the dummy solution works see answer above :)